# Nginx server header error 403 forbidden how to solve

Tags: wordpress, nginx, server, sitemap, web-development-server

My websites pages are not getting updated and server status code 503 ....i checked server header in seotoolbook server header it show 403 error.due to which sitemap is not loading correctly and page indexing is really slow.please suggested me what yo do i ask freelancer developer to fix it they are saying don't know what it
Error-
http://tools.seobook.com/server-header-checker/?url=Npsc.co.in+&useragent=8&protocol=11

Comment: its cloudflare blocking, not your nginx

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question and it is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Non-programming questions about your website should be asked on [webmasters.se]. However, questions that are specific to one website are off-topic there.  Please remove the link to your site and include enough other information about the question to be able to answer it before re-asking there.

Comment: But i asked on google webmaster they said they have no idea about i though asking here might help